# Apache Camel FTP file list?

Tags: apache-camel

With Apache Camel I need to solve a scenario where a watch folder may contain many versions of a data file, each one will have the same filename prefix but include a version tag suffix. For example, files will be uploaded with a single character appended to the filename like abc123**a**.csv, abc123**b**.csv, abc123**c**.csv and in this case I olny need to retrieve abc123**c**.csv and delete the others. Any idea of how to do this with Camel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the files Z..A and then you can use a CBR or Filter to only process the first file in a given name series and then drop the others, and then delete them all afterwards (assuming you need to delete a, b and c)

Comment: Camel is still reading the entire contents of each file just to sort/filter by the filename, is there anyway to stop that? The files are many and large and I don't want to pull back the contents of every file.

Comment: Oh, ignore that, I just spotted the "download=false" option in the docs. Apologies.

Comment: I used a filter to accept only filenames of the correct format and then used an aggregation strategy to keep only the latest version of each report.